# Magento 1.9.1.1 conflict with PHP 5.4.28 php-fpm gzip compression

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4, magento-connect, ce-1.9.1.1, gzip

After upgrading to PHP 5.4.28, Magento Connect Downloader is broken. The iframe downloader won't work. Screenshot below. Disabling php-fpm gzip compression allows Magento Connect Downloader to work normally.

Isn't the php-fpm gzip compression extension needed by Magento? How can this be fixed correctly?

UPDATE: Tried on PHP 5.5 with fresh Magento install. The issue persists.

[image: Magento Connect Downloader not showing the iframe downloader.]

Comment: keep gzip enabled in server config, and disable compression in php.ini

Comment: Won't php.ini be overwritten when Magento is updated?

Comment: no, i dont think that magento have any php.ini files enabled/active

Comment: Yes, I just checked. It only has a sample php.ini file. Would you know if PHP zlib.output_compression is needed by Magento to run correctly? I'm not really sure, if it might be needed by some function, etc.